# Ставить ли запятую в предложении

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Возможно, что ты узнаешь какая я

Comment: Или может быть так "возможно, что ты узнаешь, какая"?

Comment: Лучше так:  Возможно, ты узнаешь, какая я.